# Why values still emitted

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs5

I have the following connectable observable:

```
//emit value every 1 second
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
const example = source
  //side effects will be executed once
  .do(() => console.log('Do Something!'))
  //do nothing until connect() is called
  .publish();

/*
  source will not emit values until connect() is called
  output: (after 5s) 
  "Do Something!"
  "Subscriber One: 0"
  "Subscriber Two: 0"
  "Do Something!"
  "Subscriber One: 1"
  "Subscriber Two: 1"
*/
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(`Subscriber One: ${val}`));

//call connect after 5 seconds, causing source to begin emitting items
setTimeout(() => {
 example.connect(); 
},5000)

setTimeout(() => {
 subscribe.unsubscribe(); 
},7000)
```

Why the source observable is still emit an item, even I unsubscribe it?

Comment: The observable does not stop doing what it does just because there are no subscribers. Either kill the observable or put the console.log function in the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.connect()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/connect.md) is basically a subscription as well, so in order to *stop* the stream, you have to *"disconnect"* it, like this e.g.:

```
let connection;
setTimeout(() => {
 connection = example.connect(); 
},5000)

setTimeout(() => {
 connection.unsubscribe();
 subscribe.unsubscribe(); 
},7000)
```